# Multiple exception messages from server - show correct one on ajax error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

This is my c# code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult RenameItem(string newName)
{
        newName = CheckIfDuplicate(newName);

        if (isInfiniteLoop.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception(isValid ? _.T("Message 111") : _.T("Message 222"));
        }
        return Json(newName);
 }
```

As you can see, it is possible for two different exception messages to be shown. This is how I handle it on the client:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Items/RenameItem",
    data: { newName: newFolderName },
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;                                                        
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        debugger;
    }
```

});

In a.responceText I have whole html. How can I get only the exception message? The RenameItem method has string return type.

Comment: Why not just return the exception message, rather than throw the exception?

Comment: @Archer The _.T function translates the message. So on client how will I know if the item was renamed or not, because the message will be translated and I cant just do simple compare. Also what if this method returned int, then that still wouldn't be a proper fix.

Comment: Fair point.  Can you not just examine the returned object and see what you want to take from it?